# something is not working in CURL scraping

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, simple-html-dom, ganon

I am trying to scrape torrentz2.eu search results by using old(dead) torrentz.eu scraper code:

when I run `http://localhost/jits/torz/api.php?key=kabali`
it showing me warning and null value.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: results_urls in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jits/torz/api.php on line 59
null
```

why?

can anybody tell me what's wrong with code.?

here is code:

```
<?php   
    $t= $_GET['key'];
    // Defining the basic cURL function
    function curl($url) {
        // Assigning cURL options to an array
        $options = Array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  // Setting cURL to follow 'location' HTTP headers
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE, // Automatically set the referer where following 'location' HTTP headers
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,   // Setting the amount of time (in seconds) before the request times out
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,  // Setting the maximum amount of time for cURL to execute queries
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // Setting the maximum number of redirections to follow
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0",  // Setting the useragent
            CURLOPT_URL => $url, // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
        );
         
        $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL 
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);   // Setting cURL's options using the previously assigned array data in $options
        $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
        curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL 
        return $data;   // Returning the data from the function 
    }
?>

<?php
    // Defining the basic scraping function
    function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
        $data = stristr($data, $start); // Stripping all data from before $start
        $data = substr($data, strlen($start));  // Stripping $start
        $stop = stripos($data, $end);   // Getting the position of the $end of the data to scrape
        $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);    // Stripping all data from after and including the $end of the data to scrape
        return $data;   // Returning the scraped data from the function
    }
?>
<?php

    $url = "https://torrentz2.eu/search?f=$t";    // Assigning the URL we want to scrape to the variable $url
    $results_page = curl($url); // Downloading the results page using our curl() funtion
    //var_dump($results_page);
    //die(); 
    $results_page = scrape_between($results_page, "<dl><dt>", "<a href=\"http://www.viewme.com/search?q=$t\" title=\"Web search results on ViewMe\">"); // Scraping out only the middle section of the results page that contains our results 
    $separate_results = explode("</dd></dl>", $results_page);   // Expploding the results into separate parts into an array

    // For each separate result, scrape the URL
    foreach ($separate_results as $separate_result) {
        if ($separate_result != "") {
            $results_urls[] =  scrape_between($separate_result, "\">", "<b>"); // Scraping the page ID number and appending to the IMDb URL - Adding this URL to our URL array
     
        }
      
    }
     
    //print_r($results_urls); // Printing out our array of URLs we've just scraped      

if($_GET["key"] === null) {
echo "Keyword Missing ";
  } else if(isset($_GET["key"])) {

       echo json_encode($results_urls);

  } 
          
       ?>
```

for old torrentz.eu scraper code ref: [GIT repo](https://github.com/shyamjos/torrentz.in-api)

Answer (score 1):

First thing you get NOTICE "Undefined variable: results_urls" because $results_urls is defined and used directly. Define it and then use it.

Do something like:-

```
    // $results_urls defined here:-
    $results_urls = [];
    // For each separate result, scrape the URL
    foreach ($separate_results as $separate_result) {
        if ($separate_result != "") {
            $results_urls[] =  scrape_between($separate_result, "\">", "<b>"); // Scraping the page ID number and appending to the IMDb URL - Adding this URL to our URL array

        }

    }
```

Secondly the null is printed because **$results_urls** is not getting populated because **$separate_results** is not getting populated correctly. It just has one value which is empty.
I debugged further and found **$results_page** value is false. So whatever you are trying to do in **"scrape_between" function** is not working as expected. Fix your function.

Comment: my fault, I declared it, thanks @umakant. 
but my real problem is I don't know how to correct scrape_between() ..
that's why I asked question here if anybody can help me to correct the code so it can scrap results.

Comment: Jeet, BTW before giving down vote to answer, tell me where did you mentioned that yours falt in question? Where does your questions says that you want to know that you only need answer to fix "scrape_between()" function?. So if you haven't mentioned this thing already in question then obviously this would be the answer.